# C# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't start debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, .net-3.5

I'm developing with the Framework 3.5 in C#. When I click "start debugging" nothing happens. I've tried with other projects(including a new project) and they won't start. Instead VS2013 project doesn't have problems. Until 10 minutes ago it worked, i don't know how to solve.
If you need more details ask. Thanks.

I tried:

- Restart Computer
- Reload Visual Studio
- Create a New Project
- Reset Configurations
- Repair Visual Studio

I noticed that with audio on when I start debugging it does the error sound without show any error message. It's like the debug is starting because the pause and stop buttons appear, but the program doesn't start. I tried to put breakpoint at the begin of the main(), nothing. While the "debugging" is started if i try to pause it appear an error message: "Unable to break execution"

I tried uninstall VS2010, it gives me "Internal Error: 1058". I used Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility, it says Uninstall complete but VS2010 is still in the computer. I don't know what kind of evil is in my computer

I use xampp, so i stopped the IIS service to keep the port 80 free, i thought that this could be the problem. Then i tried to start IIS service and gives me this error: "Cannot start service w3svc on computer '.'" so i followed this [IIS w3svc error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023622/iis-w3svc-error) and it worked, IIS now starts and i was able to uninstall VS2010. Well then I reinstalled VS2010 hoping the problem was solved. I was wrong, debug still doesn't start, same problem as above.

Comment: Try CTRL+SHIFT+ESC, close off any devenv process or Visual Studio-related process. Try repairing Visual Studio.

Comment: restart your computer first of all

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Debugging doesn't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374530/debugging-doesnt-start)

Comment: What kind of applications is it? e.g. windows forms, asp.net etc.

Comment: I tried to reload VS, i restarted the computer twice and i tried [Debugging doesn't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374530/debugging-doesnt-start) resetting configuration and creating a new project, also a new projet with only one form doesn't start. It's a Windows Form application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I formatted and reinstalled Windows.