# Debugging Spawns A Non Terminable Process, and CLI not launching

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2013, process, terminate

I've been fighting this little problem for a while now, so I'm really hoping I can get some help. I've been looking for a solution to this, and I found this SO question: [Debugging doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374530/debugging-doesnt-start).

My issue is somewhat similar to the issue discussed here, except that my issue is a two-parter.

Part 1: Similar to the issue discussed on the other question. (Debug Window Doesn't show up)

When I attempt to launch my Windows 32 console application project (The simple kind that opens in the windows CLI). The CLI (or CMD) window doesn't open, and windows idles giving me a spinning cursor wheel. Visual Studio IDE (I'm using VS 2013 Community) becomes unresponsive and I cannot access any menus, or use any hotkey to "Stop Debugging". One difference from the provided SO question though, is that when I try to launch "MyProject.exe" from my project's "Debug" folder I get the same result as attempting to debug in the IDE.

Part 2: Unkillable Process

When I try to close my debug application in the windows task manager, it is not listed as an ongoing process. However, whenever I try to manipulate, delete, or otherwise modify my Project.exe application (in my Project's "Debug" folder), windows informs me that the application is in use. Confused by this, I downloaded two applications. The first was Process explorer, which showed me that I did in fact have 2 instances of "MyProject.exe" running. The second was Process Hacker, which also showed me 2 instances of "MyProject.exe". However, neither of these programs were able to terminate either of the "MyProject.exe" processes.

I am capable of terminating the processes for visual studio and restarting the IDE, however, because the "MyProject.exe" processes are still running. Building always fails with the error

"Error  1   error LNK1168: cannot open C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\MyProject\Debug\MyProject.exe for writing"

Whenever I restart my computer, the lock files (as expected) are removed, and the "MyProject.exe" processes disappear. I can restart VS and everything works, but if I try to Debug (pressing "Start Debugging" or F5) the same issue occurs.
A process of my program is started ("MyProject.exe"), but the CLI window where my program's text should appear doesn't show up. Visual studio locks up, and "MyProject.exe" persists until the next restart because "MyProcess.exe" cannot be terminated.

My solution configuration is set to "Debug", Solution Platforms = Win32.
I have tried creating a new blank console project in VS 2013 and I get the same result: code builds fine, but I have the same debugging issue. I get an identical result with a quickly assembled "Hello World" project.

Sorry for being a noob, but honestly. I really don't know what's going on, so any help is greatly appreciated.

(Note: Running Windows 10 with VS2013)

EDIT (UPDATE):
So, I'm having the same problem with several programs in Windows 10 (most notably Allegorithmic's Substance Painter). So it looks like this may actually be an OS problem. Several of my programs whenever I try to launch them do the same thing...the program acts like it's going to launch, but then no usable window appears. Looking at my processes I can see that the process has been started, but it is once again unkillable. For reference, I am using Windows 10 Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.17).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem might be Avast, if you are running it. I had exactly the same issues until I uninstalled it. Had upgraded to Win10 and VS2013 just froze, same as you described.

Cheers.