# How to stop debug opening a new Chrome window instead of a tab? Visual Studio 2017.7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

With Visual Studio / MVC, when clicking debug, it's always launched the local site as a new tab in my currently open Chrome window.

With the 2017.7 update, now it launches a new window every time.

Is there any way to change back to loading it into a tab? I don't like the "new Chrome window every time" behavior

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop browser closing automatically when you stop debugging on VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729535/how-to-stop-browser-closing-automatically-when-you-stop-debugging-on-vs-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, just noticed a new answer in one of my previous questions covers this

[How to stop browser closing automatically when you stop debugging on VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729535/how-to-stop-browser-closing-automatically-when-you-stop-debugging-on-vs-2017/50255986#50255986)