# Replacing multiple words in a string sentence C#

Tags: c#, string, replace, char, stringbuilder

**Hello guys, I don't need the answer but I would look to know and find out what I'm doing wrong. As a beginner I got a very "easy" assignment in my studies. I need to create a string and inside this string I need to replace some words by other words without using the for loop as so: ( also I want to print it but I got no clue where to put Console.WriteLine and google searching for 1 hour didn't work or asking a colleage.**

/* Excersice: use with stringbuilder
             * cat becomes littlecat
             * dog becomes littledog
             * mouse becomes littlemouse
             * words the must be replace by a
             * do not use a loop*/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Opgavens_leerpad_3_oefening
{
    class Program
    {
        static string Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            string dogCat = new string("Can the cat find the mouse without waking the dog.");

            static string replacethisstring(string dogCat);
            {
                hondKat = dogCat.Replace("cat", "littlecat");
                hondKat = dogCat.Replace("dog", "littldog");
                hondKat = dogCat.Replace("mouse", "littlemouse");
                hondKat = dogCat.Replace("the", "a");
                return dogCat;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error CS5001: Program does not contain a static "Main" method suitable for an entry point **( I don't get this doesn't almost any program starts with this static Main args? )**

Error CS8112: replacethisstring(string)' is a local function and must therefore always have a body. **( I just gave it a body right? I opened the { and close it } and put a replace with return. )**

Comment: `Main` method declaration should `static void Main(string[] args)`, note `void`

Comment: you can do the replacements in one line hondKat = dogat.Replace().Replace() etc..

Comment: There is one `;` too much. Write `static string replacethisstring(string dogCat)` instead of `static string replacethisstring(string dogCat);`

Comment: Or `Main` can return `int`...but not `string` or anything else besides `void` and `int`.

Comment: `I don't need the answer` then why did you ask the question?

Answer (score 3):

The method declaration ends with `;` that’s the reason for **CS8112**

The Main method has to return `void` (or ‘int’ )you’ve modified it to `string`, that’s the reason for **CS5001**

If you want the program to print the output on the console use:

```
using System;

....

 Console.WriteLine(output)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response ! I just noticed when i change some of these i get new errors frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your main should have a void as return type. string is not allowed but int is an option ([see reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/#overview))
2. You cannot have `;` at the end of a function declaration that has a body to it.
3. You have to declare a variable before you can use it ... string hondKat;
4. See the use of StringBuilder in the below code instead of string.

```
namespace Opgavens_leerpad_3_oefening
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("Can the cat find the mouse without waking the dog.");
            sb = replacethisstring(sb);

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine(); // To Stop the Console from closing.

            static StringBuilder replacethisstring(StringBuilder dogCat)
            {
                dogCat = dogCat.Replace("cat", "littlecat");
                dogCat = dogCat.Replace("dog", "littldog");
                dogCat = dogCat.Replace("mouse", "littlemouse");
                dogCat = dogCat.Replace("the", "a");
                return dogCat;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You can place the function within the Main or outside. Normally you would find functions outside of the Main class.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    ...
    }

    public static string replacethisstring(string dogCat)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: `use with stringbuilder` and... :)

Comment: This works perfectly thank you :D Just a few questions though stop console from closing with readline? If i click debug my command screen doesnt close if i delete readline. and why did you use toString()?

Comment: Stop closing debug window [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729535/how-to-stop-browser-closing-automatically-when-you-stop-debugging-on-vs-2017). You have to use `ToString()` to print a `StringBuilder` to the console. `StringBuilder` is an object and cant be printed like a string. You have to get the string representation by using `ToString()` method on a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Having several issues like typos, syntax error etc.
Additionally, the excercise having a condition that needs to use with stringbuilder.

So, try this.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Can the cat find the mouse without waking the dog?");
        sb = replacethisstring(sb);

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static StringBuilder replacethisstring(StringBuilder dogCat)
    {
        StringBuilder hondKat = dogCat.Replace("cat", "littlecat");
        hondKat = dogCat.Replace("the", "a");
        hondKat = dogCat.Replace("dog", "littledog");
        hondKat = dogCat.Replace("mouse", "littlemouse");
        return hondKat;
    }
```